# F# Tuple Constant never initializes

Tags: f#, tuples, libraries, program-entry-point

I've declared a tuple like this:

```
module MyModule =
  let private INVALID_TUPLE = ("0", DateTime.MinValue)
```

When I reference it lower in the module, it's always null:

```
let private invalidForNone someOtherTuple =
  match someOtherTuple with
  | None -> INVALID_TUPLE  // it's null
  | Some(t) -> t
```

Further, when I place a breakpoint on the tuple declaration, it never hits.

If I do the exact same thing in a script (fsx) file, start debugging, execute, the breakpoint on the tuple declaration hits and the reference to the tuple is good.

ILSpy for my module shows that there is some startup code generated that has a Main method that creates INVALID_TUPLE.  Apparently, that's not running for some reason?

Here is a sample that reproduces the behavior (now that I realize it has something to do with the way MSTest executes the code).  Call this from a C# unit test; result will be null.  In fact, no breakpoint in the F# code will execute at all.

```
module NullTupleTest
open System

let private INVALID_TUPLE = ("invalid", DateTime.MinValue)

let private TupleTest someTuple =
  match someTuple with
  | None -> INVALID_TUPLE
  | Some(dt) -> dt

let Main = TupleTest None
```

Comment: How do you know that it's null? Is something actually not working somewhere?

Comment: Well yes, I get an NRE downstream, and I also know it's null because the debugger tells me so.

Comment: Debugger is unreliable. Don't rely on it. Can you show where you get the NRE and how the supposedly null value gets there? Or provide another minimal reproducible example? Also, see "[How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: I can't repro. I tried `let test = invalidForNone None` and `MyModule.test` outside. It returns the tuple.

Comment: I think I have seen this behaviour before - when running code from a test runner (rather than in a "normal" way). It was somehow not executing the static initializer of the module, but I'm not entirely sure how to reproduce or avoid that.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Yes, running from MSTest unit tests.  Same code in console app initializes fine (breakpoint on tuple hits).

Comment: @FyodorSoikin  Sample added (didn't know it was MSTest related).  Debugger is unreliable?  Thus, F# is not production usable?  Obviously, that's what any team on earth would say if that's truly the case.

Comment: @dudeNumber4 Are you compiling the test project as a library or as an executable? (I think this might work with libraries, but perhaps not with executables.)

Comment: @TomasPetricek  C# test project is library (MSTest default).

Comment: As for F# being production ready - there is a large number of companies using it for production (http://fsharp.org/testimonials) and perhaps the most successful Microsoft-tech based startup uses it heavily (https://tech.jet.com/blog/2015/03-22-on-how-jet-chose). F# itself works great, though it does not get always get perfect treatment in all MS products (like in MSTest).

Comment: @dudeNumber4 The question was about the F# project - is that a library or an executable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131742/discussion-between-dudenumber4-and-tomas-petricek).

Comment: @dudeNumber4 F# is production ready. Visual Studio debugger is not.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin  I guess I'm confused.  What other IDE would one use?

Comment: There is no better IDE than Visual Studio at the moment (in my opinion). There seems to be a misunderstanding here: the claim that a thing is the best thing in existence does not imply that it's perfect. It's sort of like with democracy :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error can happen when you run code compiled as an executable in a way that does not run the `Main` method of the compiled executable - for example by referencing it from a library or by using unit test runner. The solution is to compile the F# project as a library and perhaps have another executable as the entry point. (Alternatively, you could also modify the code to avoid `let` bound global values, but I'd prefer the first approach.)

This is caused by the fact that the F# compiler handles initialization differently for code compiled as an executable and for code compiled as a library.

- For libraries, the initialization code is put in a static constructor, which is executed when the field is accessed the first time
- For executables, the initialization code is put in the `Main` method and it runs when the application starts (but only when it starts as a normal executable).

I think the reason for this is that the F# compiler tries to keep the order in which initialization happens (from top to bottom). For executables, this can be done by running initializers in the `Main` method. For libraries, there is no reliable way of doing that (because libraries have no "initialization") and so using static constructors is the next best opion.